# /etc/init.d/puppet doesn't exist in puppet agent

Tags: puppet

I've followed this instructions to install the puppet agent in a docker with ubuntu 16.04.
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/install_linux.html

So I've excecuted this

```
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-xenial.deb
dpkg -i puppet5-release-xenial.deb
apt update
apt-get install puppet-agent
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true
```

The last line to start the service fails for this reason:

```
Error: Could not find init script for 'puppet'
Error: /Service[puppet]/ensure: change from 'stopped' to 'running' failed: Could not find init script for 'puppet'
service { 'puppet':
  ensure => 'stopped',
  enable => 'false',
}
```

The problem I think is that /etc/init.d/puppet doesn't exist.

The installer puppet agent version is 5.5.1.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Well this is strange.  Puppet normally expects to manage services on Ubuntu 16.04 via systemd.  It is normal and to be expected that its packages for this OS do not contain an initscript (they should contain systemd service-control files instead).  Have you, perhaps, avoided installing systemd into your container?

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger. Thanks for your answer. Indeed I didn't install systemd in the container, I will investigate about that.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd, along with other init processes, are not installed by design, as you should be running your processes via an entrypoint or command option. In other words, the container should be running the command you are interested in, not a wrapper or bootstapping application.

In your case, puppet actually has a container that you can run out of the box for smoke-testing and such. You can find it here:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker

If though you are hell bent on running puppet agent jobs via systemd, you can actually attempt this with an example from a Redhat blog here:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/